# Pinvoke command length is incorrect

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I am trying to get the **FILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFO** with the `GetFileInformationByHandle` function. All my values are set to zero after calling.
 I get the win32 error message: 
 **ERROR_BAD_LENGTH
The program issued a command but the command length is incorrect.**

```
IntPtr handle = CreateFile(dir, EFileAccess.GenericRead, EFileShare.Read, IntPtr.Zero, ECreationDisposition.OpenExisting, EFileAttributes.BackupSemantics | EFileAttributes.Normal, IntPtr.Zero);
FILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFO fileStruct = new FILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFO();
GetFileInformationByHandleEx(handle, FILE_INFO_BY_HANDLE_CLASS.FileIdBothDirectoryInfo, out fileStruct, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(fileStruct));
```

FILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFO structure

```
    typedef struct _FILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFO {
    DWORD         NextEntryOffset;
    DWORD         FileIndex;
    LARGE_INTEGER CreationTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER LastAccessTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER LastWriteTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER ChangeTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER EndOfFile;
    LARGE_INTEGER AllocationSize;
    DWORD         FileAttributes;
    DWORD         FileNameLength;
    DWORD         EaSize;
    CCHAR         ShortNameLength;
    WCHAR         ShortName[12];
    LARGE_INTEGER FileId;
    WCHAR         FileName[1];
    } FILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFO, *PFILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFO
```

In C#

```
    public struct FILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFO
    {
        uint NextEntryOffset;
        uint FileIndex;
        LARGE_INTEGER CreationTime;
        LARGE_INTEGER LastAccessTime;
        LARGE_INTEGER LastWriteTime;
        LARGE_INTEGER ChangeTime;
        LARGE_INTEGER EndOfFile;
        LARGE_INTEGER AllocationSize;
        uint FileAttributes;
        uint FileNameLength;
        uint EaSize;
        char ShortNameLength;
        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 12)]
        string ShortName;
        LARGE_INTEGER FileId;
        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 1)]
        string FileName;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 8)]
    struct LARGE_INTEGER
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public Int64 QuadPart;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public UInt32 LowPart;
        [FieldOffset(4)]
        public Int32 HighPart;
    }
```

Comment: Don't you need [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)] on FILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFO too?

Comment: @David Hefferman - really? MSDN says "The common language runtime uses the Auto layout value by default. To reduce layout-related problems associated with the Auto value, C#, Visual Basic, and C++ compilers specify Sequential layout for value types."

Comment: @David, ok understood, thanks for clarification - your answer was spot on anyway, always best to debug on the unmanaged side as soon as you can see what's been marshalled. So +1 from me.

Comment: @roger No, I had a brain fart there. Sequential is default for a struct, Auto for a class. Getting confused!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character set for ByValTStr is determined by the CharSet argument of the StructLayout attribute. Since you've not specified that, the default of 8 bit ANSI is used. If you specify the CharSet as CharSet.Unicode then that should deal with the problem. Add this attribute to your struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, 
    CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
```

For the purposes of debugging write a C++ program that outputs the size of the struct. Make sure that your C# program matches that value.